# Using output from a module as email text

Tags: python, string, smtp

I have a project going where I want to create a dadjoke emailer. I want the joke form the dadjoke module to be the body of my email that is sent as an email using python. I have a code that runs but I can´t figure out how the print(dadjoke.joke) can become the email text body.

If you could guide me it would be much helpful.

BR

Andreas

```
import smtplib

#The joke
from dadjokes import Dadjoke
dadjoke = Dadjoke()
print(dadjoke.joke)

# list of email_id to send the mail
li = ["example@gmail.com"]
  
for dest in li:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login("un@hotmail.com", "pw")

    #Email content
    subject = "Weekly dadjoke!"
    text = "\nThanks for explaining the word 'many' to me. It means a lot." , str(dadjoke.joke)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, text)
    
    #Email send details
    s.sendmail("sender@hotmail.com", dest, message)

    #Closing session
    s.quit()
```

I´ve tried to get the joke in using str() but that didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually look at the text varaibles value as you have , you get this result:

```
("\nThanks for explaining the word 'many' to me. It means a lot.", 'What did the ocean say to the shore? Nothing, it just waved.')
```

That's because something, something is always a tuple and print just has a good method for printing each one out separately. Try adding two strings together:

```
'\n' + dadjoke.joke
```

Or use a f string:

```
f'\n{dadjoke.joke}'
```

Either will produce a new line character followed by the joke:

```
'\nWhat did the ocean say to the shore? Nothing, it just waved.'
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your swift respons. Both options work, excellent. When adding more text to the email body, that was a bit tricky. I had to use the same format as for the dadjoke ie f'\n{"asdfasdfasdf"}' + \n\n + and next. But it works! First time putting a Q to Stack overflow! Thanks NPGuy